# pygobject creating a drag and drop source

Tags: python, pygobject, gtk3

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def drag_data_get_cb(widget, drag_context, selection_data, info, time):
    print selection_data.get_data_type()
    print widget.get_text()
    return widget.get_text()

def drag_begin_cb(widget, dragcontext):
    print dragcontext, widget
    return dragcontext

label = Gtk.Label()
label.drag_source_set(Gdk.ModifierType.BUTTON1_MASK, [], Gdk.DragAction.COPY)
label.set_text("Drag Me!")
label.connect("drag_data_get", drag_data_get_cb)
label.connect("drag_begin", drag_begin_cb)

window = Gtk.Window()
window.add(label)
window.connect("delete_event", Gtk.main_quit)
window.set_default_size(300, 250)
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

ive been hitting my head against a wall over this for a few days now,
can anyone tell me why this doesnt allow me to drag text into other widgets? neither of the drag events fire at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says in this [tutorial](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeLove/DragNDropTutorial) that you cannot use widgets without windows, such as `Gtk.Label` as drag and drop sources. You can replace the label with a button for instance:

```
label = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Drag Me!")
```

in order for this example to work.

Comment: ah ok, i just assumed since the drag events are all inherited from gtkwidget that i could use them on a label

Comment: one thing i did discover also is that under gobject u seem to need to call   'code' label.drag_source_add_uri_targets()
 label.drag_source_add_text_targets() 'code' unlike pygtk