# Workaround for making Gtk.Label a drag source?

Tags: drag-and-drop, gtk, draggable, pygtk

I'm new to Gtk DnD, and I'm trying to make a Gtk.Label a drag source.

It seems it is *not* directly possible according to [pygobject creating a drag and drop source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704017/pygobject-creating-a-drag-and-drop-source)

The workaround seems to be a surrounding invisible event box [GtkEventBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEventBox.html) (thanks @jku)

But the doc says:
"There is one unexpected issue for an invisible event box that has its window below the child. Since the input-only window is not an ancestor window of any windows that descendent widgets of the event box create, events on these windows aren’t propagated up by the windowing system, but only by GTK+. The practical effect of this is if an event isn’t in the event mask for the descendant window (see gtk_widget_add_events()), it won’t be received by the event box."

So, can I have a invisible GtkEventBox *above* my Label ?
If the GtkEventBox is below, does the GtkLabel catch events and bubble them up ?

Answer for me :

Surrounding the GtkLabel with a GtkEventBox works without any problem. 
And the surrounded GtkLabel still receives the DnD drop events (with and without "visible-window"=False).

Since it worked, I havent played with  set_above_child at all.

Comment: I haven't played with DnD on EventBox widgets, but does calling [eventbox.set_above_child(True)](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkeventbox.html#method-gtkeventbox--set-above-child) make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GtkEventBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEventBox.html) was designed for handling input events for widgets that don't have their own GdkWindow. Put your label inside an eventbox and use the eventbox as the dnd source.

An HBox will not work because it has no GdkWindow either.

Comment: The label won't catch any events because it does not have a GdkWindow (if it did you wouldn't need the eventbox at all). So I don't see how the event propagation problem would appear. Why not just try -- it's not like we're talking about a massive amount of code.

Comment: btw, when talking about a small amount of code I referred to event handling in general (like mouseclicks): I don't want to give the impression that DnD is very simple and straight forward...

Comment: It works without any problem. And the surrounded GtkLabel still receives the DnD drop events. (with and without visible-window=False).
Thanks a lot !